# including a class in a groovy file

Tags: groovy

I have tried to include a class(literally cut and pasted from one groovy file to another).

I get the below error

Error(s) in Groovy Script: startup failed, Script1.groovy: 101: Class definition not expected here. Possible attempt to use inner class. Inner classes not supported, perhaps try using a closure instead.

The objective is to separate the whole static logic separately.

Comment: If you show the code or even just some of it around line 101 we might be able to spot the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got what looks like an internal `class`

```
    class Maps
```

Right in the middle of the method

```
public static void populateInstance(List lookup_1, List lookup_2, List lookup_3, List lookup_4, 
                                    List lookup_5, List lookup_6, List lookup_7){
```

---

Also, as this is Groovy, declaring all those getters shouldn't be necessary

---

And

```
import com.mobRet.*
```

isn't needed as you're already in that package. Also

```
import java.util.ArrayList
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List
```

Can be removed as Groovy imports them by default

---

And inside the `populateInstance` method, you can change all those:

```
    tariffAllowance = new ArrayList();
    lookup_1.each { offer ->
        tariffAllowance.add(offer)
    }

    fmb = new ArrayList();
    lookup_2.each { offer ->
        fmb.add(offer)
    }
```

blocks to:

```
    tariffAllowance = lookup_1.collect()
    fmb = lookup_2.collect()
```

---

You also seem to be making a singleton that can have all of it's data changed by calling `populateInstance`.  In a multi-threaded environment, the chances of this being wrong are huge (effectively this is one huge global variable)

Comment: Yes Tim,I would need this to be a singleton. Doing it intentionally as per the requirements. Thank you very much for your answer...you have always been a star...cheers

Comment: lookup_1.collect did not work, org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodSelectionException: Could not find which method collect() to invoke from this list:
  public java.util.Collection java.util.Collection#collect(java.util.Collection, groovy.lang.Closure)
  public java.util.List java.util.Collection#collect(groovy.lang.Closure)

Comment: Really old version of Groovy yeah? `collect()` has been part of groovy since 1.8.5.

Comment: Yeah it is 1.5.6, I am just using groovy as a script as part of Think Analytics code...Thanks anyway

Comment: Ouch that's kinda old ;-)  You can do:  `lookup_1.collect { it }`

Comment: Tim, one more question, how do I refer to the class "maps" of this groovy script in another groovy script. I have created an instance of this as MobileDataSource mobileDataSource = MobileDataSource.getInstance() and tried to place mobileDataSource.maps, it throws an error. how do I do that?

Comment: Make it a static class and try `new MobileDataSource.Maps()`? Or extract it out from being an inner class to being a class on its own? It's hard to see from the huge example above...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38092/discussion-between-techie-and-tim-yates)

Comment: I dont have priveleges to chat :-( I made the class as static class Maps and to use it as a variable. I used def maps = new MobileDataSource.Maps(), which doesnt seem to work...sorry to bother and appreciate your help